# BizTalk orchestration log event 10034

Tags: c#, ado.net, biztalk, biztalk-2010

in this BizTalk orchestration, my .net class will access ADO .Net and get data from database. However, when I sent a message to the orchestration, the following error occurred. I am wondering if the orchestration cannot access the database?  Please advise, thanks.

> xlang/s engine event log entry:
>   Uncaught exception (see the 'inner
>   exception' below) has suspended an
>   instance of service 'BizTalk_Server_test.BizTalk_Orchestration_1(13b5f384-5a0b-0ad8-3ef9-489d80200b58)'.
>
> The service instance will remain
>   suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated. If resumed the
>   instance will continue from its last
>   persisted state and may re-throw the
>   same unexpected exception.
>
> InstanceId:
>   5299e71a-0092-4bef-a770-8153181b2b8a
>   Shape name: Expression_1 ShapeId:
>   bc04ec19-bc1e-40a7-aaed-75a9b0628891
>   Exception thrown from: segment 1,
>   progress 6 Inner exception: The
>   specified named connection is either
>   not found in the configuration, not
>   intended to be used with the
>   EntityClient provider, or not valid.
>   Exception type: ArgumentException
>   Source: System.Data.Entity Target
>   Site: Void
>   ChangeConnectionString(System.String)
>
> The following is a stack trace that
>   identifies the location where the
>   exception occured at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String
>   newConnectionString) at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String
>   connectionString) at
>   g2.interop.Abbyy.Reader.XmlReader.CaseNumReader()
>   at
>   BizTalk_Server_test.BizTalk_Orchestration_1.segment1(StopConditions
>   stopOn) at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment
>   s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception&
>   exp)

Comment: Where is the connection string?

Comment: If connecting to a database you would be better of using either the SQL adapter or WCF-SQL adapter.  Doing it in you own class means you don't automatically get the multi-threading, re-try logic & guaranteed transactions that BizTalk gives you out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not passing the connection string in the context when it's being created and it's looking for it in a config file, you will need to put the connection string in the btsntsvc.exe.config file.